# How to use OR or AND in fnmatch.filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you apply OR or AND in the fnmatch filter?

```
pattern = "*2006*|*2005*"
fnmatch.filter(list,pattern)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fnmatch` does not support that (in the general case), the syntax is quite limited - same as shell-style wildcards. You'll have to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re), or call filter twice and union the results (for OR) or intersect the results (for AND).

Comment: I called the filter twice. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose `5` and `6` in square brackets to denote a character set:

```
pattern = "*200[56]*"
fnmatch.filter(list,pattern)
```

Please refer to `fnmatch`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html) for details on the supported patterns.

Comment: This is OR. AND isn't possible.

Comment: I'm implementing what the OP's code intends to do, which is clearly meant to be an OR operation.

Comment: Right, and well done :) The question asks how to implement OR and AND, so I thought it was pertinent to point out that this is "OR", and "AND" can't be done :)

Comment: If it goes to year 2009 or year 2010.We won't be able to use the `[910]`

Comment: No, the OP asks for how to implement OR *or* AND, not OR *and* AND. So I answered by picking the OR part.